# How to get formated order addresses

Tags: orders, shipping-address, billing-address

I know we can get formated customer addresses by calling,

```
$data = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getFormated();
```

Is there a similar way to get shipping address and billing address of a order as a string?

This gives me a error

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getData()->getFormated()
```

Comment: Oops silly mistake. getData was the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$billing = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFormated();
$shipping = $order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated();
```

`getFormated` supports an optional parameter that can be `html` or `text`.

Comment: What I want is formated order shipping address. Not customer shipping address

Comment: @Dan. Sorry, I should read more carefully. I edited the answer.

Comment: Hey guys, great question and answers, however I have a slight problem, what if address line 2 is supplied, how do I get that?

Comment: `getFormated()` is returning null inside Observer, using `$order = $observer->getOrder()`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason inside custom module observer on Magento 2.3 it didn't worked for me so I wrote below code for address summary. You can copy and save time ;)

```
$shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
echo $shipping_address->getData("firstname").' '.$shipping_address->getData("lastname")."<br/>".
$shipping_address->getData("company")."<br/>".
$shipping_address->getData("street")."<br/>".
$shipping_address->getData("city")."<br/>".
$shipping_address->getData("region")."<br/>".
$shipping_address->getData("country_id")."<br/>".
$shipping_address->getData("postcode")."<br/>".
"T: ".$shipping_address->getData("telephone");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like most of these answers are out of date. As of Magento 2.4.3 you'll want to do the following.

**(Using Object Manager as the easiest way to refernce the right classes. Use dependency injection if you can.)**

```
$objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
$addressConfig = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config::class);
$addressMapper = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper::class);
$renderer    = $addressConfig->getFormatByCode('text')->getRenderer();

// Where $address instanceof \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface
$addressData = $addressMapper->toFlatArray($address);

// Where $address instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address
$customerAddress = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface::class, ['data' => $address->getData()]);
$addressData = $addressMapper->toFlatArray($customerAddress);
```