# How to get the billing address from a quote instance: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, adminhtml, quote, billing-address

I have a custom module in which I need to get the order details. I am using the below code to get the orders from quotes in admin end,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$options = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
$_order = $options->load($_quoteId);
```

Here I am getting the quote and order details. I am getting the billing address In case I try to print it as below,

```
print_r($_order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet());
print_r($_order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstName());
```

However, when I am using the getFormattedAddress() like below, I don't get anything.

```
echo $block->getFormattedAddress($_order->getBillingAddress());
```

In my block I have added the getFormattedAddress() function as below,

```
    public function getFormattedAddress(Address $address) {
    return $this->addressRenderer->format($address, 'html');
}
```

This gives me an error as,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Quotes::getFormattedAddress() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address, instance of Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address given
```

I tried to go through some of the belwo links but could not manage to get the solution of my problem,

- [Magento 2 Get Order Billing Details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131983/magento-2-get-order-billing-details)
- [Not getting order shipping address in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143776/not-getting-order-shipping-address-in-magento2)
- [How to get formated order addresses](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96977/how-to-get-formated-order-addresses)

The issue here is, getFormattedAddress() expects an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address whereas, I am passing an address of Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address.

Is there any way to use getFormattedAddress() using the quote address?

PS: I know the using objectManager directly is not recommended and I have plans to change it once I get the billing and shipping address.

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Which class have you used for **Address** in  `public function getFormattedAddress(Address $address)`

Comment: I am using \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These error comes from a method `public function getFormattedAddress(Address $address)` because you expect to get the order address as a first argument. Try to remove the argument validation:

```
public function getFormattedAddress($address) {
    return $this->addressRenderer->format($address, 'html');
}
```

However if you are using the `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer` class there should be Order Address, so I'll recommend you to use the `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress` model and convert your quote address to the order address:

```
public function getFormattedAddress($address) {
    if ($address instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address) {
        $address = $this->quoteToOrderAddressConverter->convert($address);
    }

    if (!$address instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address) {
        throw new \Exception(__('Expected instance of \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address, got ' . get_class($address)));
    }

    return $this->addressRenderer->format($address, 'html');
}
```

where the `$this->quoteToOrderAddressConverter` instance of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress`. Add it in using dependency injection (prefered) or using the `ObjectManager`.

Comment: @coderun I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

In `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer` Class, first agrument passed with type hint order address object.

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address;
public function format(Address $address, $type)
{

}
```

So we can not passed quote address object. you can get Address Id from Quote address object and format the address like below:

```
public function __construct(
    /* add below dependencies In your class construct */
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper
) {
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->_addressConfig = $addressConfig;
    $this->addressMapper = $addressMapper;
}
```

Add below code in your function to get formatted address:

```
$addressData = array();
$addressId = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();
try {
    $addressObject = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);

    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\RendererInterface $renderer */
    $renderer = $this->_addressConfig->getFormatByCode('html')->getRenderer();
    $addressData = $renderer->renderArray($this->addressMapper->toFlatArray($addressObject));
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();die;
}

echo $addressData;
die;
```

Hope this help !!